# Wrap C pointer in struct with NumPy array in Python using SWIG

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

I have the following C struct:

```
struct my_struct {
    int some_int;
    const int *some_int_vector;
}
```

that I want to interface (using SWIG) from Python as follows:

```
>>> ms = my_struct()
>>> ms.some_int = 5
>>> ms.some_int_vector = [1,2,3]
```

Wrapping the struct itself seems to work: I can assign values to `some_int`. However, for `some_int_vector`, I get `NoneType` in Python. If I assign something to it, I get the error

```
TypeError: in method 'my_struct_some_int_vector_set', argument 2 of type 'int_t const *'
```

After hours of searching, I'm still confused how to interface this. I'm aware of `numpy.i`, but using it seems to require to know the vector dimensions beforehand.

I also tried a typemap as suggested in the [SWIG tutorial](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn40):

```
%typemap(in) int_t *vec (int_t temp[$1_dim0]) {

int i;
if (!PySequence_Check($input)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Expected a sequence");
    SWIG_fail;
  }
if (PySequence_Length($input) != $1_dim0) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Size mismatch. Expected $1_dim0 elements");
    SWIG_fail;
}
for (i = 0; i < $1_dim0; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PySequence_GetItem($input,i);
    if (PyNumber_Check(o)) {
        temp[i] = (float) PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
    } else {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Sequence elements must be numbers");
        SWIG_fail;
    }
}
$1 = temp;
}
```

but this does not seem to change anything.

Comment: I have no experience with swig but did you try using a tuple instead of a list? As in `ms.some_int_vector = (1,2,3)`

Comment: I tried, but I get the same error message as with a list.